# How can I add a url to an alert?

Tags: swift, nsurl, uialertcontroller

Is there a method to add an url for users looking for additional information?  My alert looks like this

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert details", message: "For more detailed information, click the link below", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    // add url here
    let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { (action) in
        print(action)
    }
    alert.addAction(okayAction)
```

The idea is to redirect them to a webpage and close the UIAlertController in the app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot add arbitrary interface to a UIAlertController. The title and message are not tappable. You cannot add further text. Instead, add another button (UIAlertAction) that directs them to the Web page. Either that, or use some other interface instead of a UIAlertController (for example, you can put up a presented view controller that *looks* like an alert).

Comment: Thanks.  Is there also the possibility to use 'alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in' to create a String associated with a URL??

Comment: I'm not sure how the text field would help you. There isn't enough room in it to show a whole URL, probably, and the user can't do anything in it that would trigger some sort of action. It's the buttons that trigger the actions. You can certainly make yourself the text field's delegate but I don't quite see how that would help you here.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I played around with the textfield a bit but you're right, the only way to handle this really is to use the buttons on uialertcontroller

Comment: If you want to make your own custom alert-like thing, here's a project of mine that will get you started: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Answer (score 1):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Default Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
let textView = UITextView()
textView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

let controller = UIViewController()

textView.frame = controller.view.frame
controller.view.addSubview(textView)
textView.backgroundColor = .clear

alert.setValue(controller, forKey: "contentViewController")

let height: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 150)
alert.view.addConstraint(height)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "http://movies.com")
let url = URL(string: "http://movies.com")

attributedString.setAttributes([.link: url ?? ""], range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))


textView.attributedText = attributedString
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
textView.isEditable = false

// Set how links should appear: blue and underlined
textView.linkTextAttributes = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
    .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
]

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
    UIAlertAction in
}
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {
    UIAlertAction in
}

alert.addAction(okAction)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)

present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

from here: [https://overcoder.net/q/1502030/кликабельный-url-на-uialertcontroller](https://overcoder.net/q/1502030/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-url-%D0%BD%D0%B0-uialertcontroller)

Comment: Looks kind of hacky... if you're going to do this much customization it would probably be better to just make your own alert view.