# Clickable url at UIAlertcontroller

Tags: ios, alert, uialertcontroller

Is it possible to create an alert with a message in it that contains text with a clickable URL, with a further redirect in Safari? Example: https://prntscr.com/lujcx5

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782288/is-it-possible-to-add-a-hyperlink-to-a-uialertcontroller

Comment: you can always create your own alert-controller lookalike thing.

Comment: This is not possible.For more information prefer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438417/how-can-i-add-a-url-to-an-alert
Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score -2):

You may want to try this,

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Default Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    let controller = UIViewController()

    textView.frame = controller.view.frame
    controller.view.addSubview(textView)
    textView.backgroundColor = .clear

    alert.setValue(controller, forKey: "contentViewController")

    let height: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 150)
    alert.view.addConstraint(height)

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "http://movies.com")
    let url = URL(string: "http://movies.com")

    attributedString.setAttributes([.link: url ?? ""], range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))


    textView.attributedText = attributedString
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView.isEditable = false

    // Set how links should appear: blue and underlined
    textView.linkTextAttributes = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
        .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
    ]

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
        UIAlertAction in
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
    }

    alert.addAction(okAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The output should look like,
[image]

Comment: This code is dangerous. It accesses private, internal structures that could change  in a future iOS update and cause the app to crash. Avoid code like this.

Comment: I'll add that it might causes a app rejection in future if Apple decides so.